# App Inventor 2 Bluetooth headset buttons

Tags: android, bluetooth, app-inventor

OK

problems 1
I am using a Bluetooth headset that has 3 buttons.

I am trying to get the button on the headset to run as if I click a button in my app.

problem 2
I am using google voice recognizer, but when it runs it uses the mic from the phone not the headset.

hope someone can help with either problem